# can't get contents of FTP page with open-uri

Tags: ruby, curl, ftp

I'm trying to get the contents of page using FTP. It's at a page like ftp://ftp.blajab.com

I've tried to use open-uri to access the page, but I keep getting this error:

```
open-uri.rb:757:in `buffer_open': no filename: #<URI::FTP ftp://ftp.jklkj
```

If I simply do open('ftp://ftp.alksdjf.com') it fails.

But, if I do open('ftp://ftp.alksdjf.com/somefilename') it'll open it.

How can I access that index page?

I can use curl in terminal to get there. I've tried net/ftp, the curb gem, capybara, and Net:FTP so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this without any libraries at all.

In my ruby I just execute a curl command and parse the response.

Like so:

```
cmd = `curl -l 'ftp://ftp.some.specialsite/'`
```

Note the back ticks and the -l flag.

The -l flag returns a list of only file names without the extra info.